# I can not receive server full response with socket.receive

Tags: sockets

I send a command to server with socket.send, server response me but i can not receive full response.
is the buffer size small?
where is the problem?!!

```
        private void send(string toSend)
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[8192];
            int dataLenght = 0;
            string ServerResponse = "";
            try
            {

                data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(toSend);
                sock.Send(data);
                data = new byte[8192];
                dataLenght = 0;

                   while (sock.Available != 0)
                    {
                     //   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
                        data = new byte[8192];
                        dataLenght = 0;
                        dataLenght = sock.Receive(data);
                        ServerResponse += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, dataLenght);
                    }

                    txtResponse.Text += toSend + ServerResponse + "\n";
                    txtResponse.SelectionStart = txtResponse.TextLength;
                    txtResponse.ScrollToCaret();

            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ee.Message, "error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            finally
            {
            }
        }
```

Comment: Which language is this? add an appropriate language tag.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the use of `Socket.Available` as an end of message test. That's not what it is, and it's not what it's for. It is up to you to keep reading until you have an entire message, whatever that may mean in your protocol. There is nothing in TCP that can help you with that. It is a byte-steam protocol only.

Comment: so what i can do to receive full response?!

Comment: @aavali: You need to define a protocol which allows the receiver to know when everything had been read. You can do this for exampe by either sending the amount of data to come before the data is sent or by defining some end-of-data marker and read until thelatter had been received.